# Is there a paper to verify Newton's law of inertia in a laboratory experiment?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations

Do you happen to know a specific paper verifying Newton's first law in a laboratory experiment? I would like to know how they verified and how many errors were observed in their setting.
It would be helpful if you could also suggest experimental papers on other Newton's laws.

Answer (score 2):

Such papers will typically be rare because papers focus on novel results. However, even if a paper is testing a completely different hypothesis, you can re-analyze their kinematic data to confirm the law.

That said, this is a *very* common experiment for freshman physics labs, where students will conduct it and then write it up in a format similar to a paper. So it gets verified directly on a routine basis, just not published in the usual journals.

Lastly, I believe Newton's original treatise actually examined the motion of planets in the context of his laws. Granted, that is not a controlled experiment, it is just an observational study. But I think Galileo *had* conducted such experiments, I think Newton extended upon them as well, though I'm not entirely sure on that detail.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I did not major physics, so I have not done such experiments (maybe did but I forgot). As for the second law, I found a recent paper verifying F = ma for small a. 
https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=2657&context=physics_articles

Comment: Newton certainly did experiments, and described them in *Principia*. Some of them were on a large scale - for example he persuaded his friend Christopher Wren (the architect who rebuilt London after the Great Fire in 1666) to let him use the dome of St Paul's Cathedral for one experiment. (That experiment which turned out to be a complete failure - the description in *Principia* is quite amusing to read.)

Answer (score 1):

The motions of the planets of our solar system provide an indirect way of assessing the first law.

If the first law would not hold good then the inverse square law of gravity would not cause regular planetary orbit.

But we know from observation that the motions of the planets can be described with a very, very high level of accuracy with the inverse square law of gravity.

After the Sun Jupiter is the next heaviest object in the Solar system. So to assess how accurately the inverse squaere law describes the motions the influence of Jupiter must be taken into account. Once the planet-planet interactions have been taken in to account only an anomalous precession of the orbit of Mercury remains (which is in the order of seconds of arc per *century*)

In physics it is very rare that something is measured directly. In many cases what is measured is influenced by several different things.

In the case of celestial motion: in order to result in the actual planetary motions *all* laws of motion must hold good concurrently. In that sense our observations of the motions of the planets do offer corroboration of Newton's first law.

The special thing about the motions of the planets is that planetary motion is the closest thing we have to *frictionless* motion.

Here on Earth it is very difficult to create circumstances such that motion is frictionless. Maybe in a vacuum chamber, but then you are limited to just that chamber.

The motions of the planets of the Solar system are in and of themselves the very largest observable display of the laws of motion.